# Will_paginate, Boosttrap Paginate, and Jquery together: Can I hide section created by the erb loop

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to create my own pagination because I am in **sandbox mode** for an **API**. `Will_paginate` attaches to the index action but won't accept the `JSON` that I have tried to populate into my `sqlite` db.

So I am making my own pagination using hide, replace, and show

```
   <% if (count % 4) == 0 %> 
      </page>
      <page id="page_section:<%= count %>">
   <% end %>
```

My coffescript code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#example').dataTable()
  return
$('#pagination0').click (event)->
  event.preventDefault()
$('#page_section:12').hide()
```

This doesn't hide `<page id="page_section:12"> ... </page>`.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your `$('#page_section:12').hide()` doesn't seems to reside inside `$(document).ready`. Try putting inside that.

Comment: Not sure about coffee script, but may be you need to indent `$('#page_section:12').hide()` within click function?

Answer (score 0):

Very sorry I didn't put in the code for the "href." I idin't put the <%= foo %> in side of the tag like `<a href="#" id="<%= foo %> </a>` this is why Jquery didn't catch the link.